# Angular Js Textbox not focus on button click

Tags: html, angularjs

Unable to focus on textbox on button click:

```
<html ng-app="CommonApp">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="HeadCtrl" ng-init='username=""'>
    <input id="UserName" type="text" class="login_boxdecor" ng-model="username" />
    <div class="login_btn_outer">
        <div class="login_btn_outer2" ng-click="cLgn();">
            <a class="btn">Login</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
var myApp = angular.module('CommonApp', []);
    myApp.controller('HeadCtrl', function($scope){
        $scope.cLgn= function(){
            if($scope.username.trim().length==0)
            {
                //Here How to focus my textbox
            }
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html ng-app="CommonApp">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="HeadCtrl" ng-init='username=""'>
    <input id="UserName" type="text" class="login_boxdecor" ng-model="username" />
    <div class="login_btn_outer">
        <div class="login_btn_outer2" ng-click="cLgn();">
            <a class="btn">Login</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
var myApp = angular.module('CommonApp', []);
    myApp.controller('HeadCtrl', function($scope){
        $scope.cLgn= function(){
            if($scope.username.trim().length==0)
            {
                document.getElementById("UserName").focus();
            }
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular.element to select your input box and can call focus(). Try something similar to below::

```
 <html ng-app="CommonApp">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="HeadCtrl" ng-init='username=""'>
    <input id="UserName" type="text" class="login_boxdecor" ng-model="username"/>
    <div class="login_btn_outer">
        <div class="login_btn_outer2" ng-click="cLgn();">
            <a class="btn">Login</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
var myApp = angular.module('CommonApp', []);
    myApp.controller('HeadCtrl', function($scope){
        $scope.focusText =false;
        $scope.cLgn= function(){
            if($scope.username.trim().length==0)
            {
                 angular.element("#UserName").focus();
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: cLgn() is getting called?? Can you verify. See running code @ http://jsfiddle.net/deathhell/UTn5y/2/

Comment: I want to focus my textbox on button click and the link you provided here is focus a textbox when mouse pointer focus a textbox.

Comment: Ohk, got it: I have just updated the answer, can u plz have a try ? put angular.element("#UserName").focus(); in your function call.

Comment: its not working but i have got the another solution by doing this document.getElementById("UserName").focus();